# Watson Conversation Service API call

Tags: android-studio, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to do a conversational bot using Conversation Service of IBM Watson. The intent, entity, dialog is ready and is in place. 
Can anyone provide me the code on how to deploy this application in Android Studio? I plan to use STT and TTS service in the application later as well, but to begin with I want to try conversation service first.Thanks in advance.

> Issue after adding Conversation service to [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud) Conversation Service does not even come at the drop down. Please help.
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Conversation readme](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/conversation) for the [Watson Developer Cloud Java SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) might be helpful. It includes installation instructions for Maven and Gradle, and an example of sending a message to the Conversation service.

As your development progresses towards using the Speech to Text and Text to Speech services, you might be interested in using the [Watson Developer Cloud Android SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk) as well. The Android SDK is designed to be used in conjunction with the Java SDK, but provides easier access to Android-specific components like the microphone, speakers, and camera. You might find it useful to refer to this [example project](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/android/myapplication/MainActivity.java) in the Android SDK repository that uses Speech to Text and Text to Speech.

Comment: Hello @Glenn, Thanks so much for the example Project, I tried it and its working perfectly (STT,Translate,TTS). I tried using Conversation Service in it too by importing the API, But i am getting the issue I added above in my original question. Can you help me figure out whats wrong? Thanks a ton.

Comment: I used async call for calling conversation API call at my Android Studio. The call is going through but I can seem to see mt dialog conversation at my phone UI. Please advice on how to see my dialog conversation at my UI interface?